# MongoDB query using distinct and limit in the same query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to return the latest reading for each device in an application from a MongoDb document.

I can get the query to return the latest reading for the application as a whole but not the latest reading for each individaul device in the application.

This is the structure of the documents in the collection:

```
  {
    _id: 5f456ab2e836990e5e7d9550,
    appID: 'helen-app',
    deviceID: 'eleanor-house',
    time: 'Tue Aug 25 2020 20:46:58 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)',
    payload: { type: 'Feature', properties: [Object], geometry: [Object] }
  }
```

There a multiple devices in one application.

This is the query currently which returns the latest readings for the whole application grouped in deviceID and in time order:

```
  col.find({ appID: user.appID }).sort({deviceID: 1, time: -1}).toArray(function(err,res){
        console.log(res)
      });
```

I have used the distinct collection method which collects all the devices associated with an application but I can't loop through each device to get the latest reading and I feel it will be more efficient to do it all in one query.

Is there a way to incorporate the distinct feature into the query above so it selects the latest reading for each device not just for the whole application?

Comment: My first thought would be your query is weird.  If you want to sort and limit, typically I've seen this follow the pattern of: `col.find({ appID: user.appID }).sort({ time: -1 }).limit(1)`.  The second `{}` inside the `find()` is usually the projection arguments in my experience.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: @Taplar Thank you!! I editied the code slightly. I left out the ```.limit()``` at the end as I believe that will limit the whole query to 1 document which won't return the latest reading for each device. Do you think there will be a way to put the something similiar to the distinct feature in the projection arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to achieve this :

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      "$match": { appID: "helen-app" } // filter docs based on appID
    },
    {
      $sort: { time: -1 } // sort in descending order
    },
    {
      $group: { _id: "$deviceID", doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } // group on `deviceID` field and push first document into `doc` field
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } // make `doc` field as new root to each document
    }
  ])
```

**Test:** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IlfL5wB7Y4M)

**Note:**

Always have dates in DB as `Date` format but not in strings and it's better to maintain at least one date field in all documents of a collection. Do not forget to create indexes and use `.explain()` to check if your queries are effectively using indexes or not.

**JFYI** - In case if your collection is too big to sort on a field and then this kind of operation can also be achieved by auto-created `_id` field as that field in MongoDB can represent a date as well plus is auto-indexed and will be fast enough, in the end, it all depends on your application, how it uses database i.e; writes to DB.

Comment: You are nothing more than a legend!!!! Thank you so much!!!! Solved my problem!!

Comment: By the way, I am now giving you a mention in the acknowledgements in my dissertation!

Comment: @HelenJohnson: Hey nevermind this is just a basic help that most people in the community would do every day. Just forget about it, things are working, nice to hear & happy coding :-)